# Facebook Graph API: retrieve comments in page that a given user commented on

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, facebook-comments

I have a page `P` and a user `U` and want to find all the posts that `U` had commented on in `P`.

How can it be done? Is there a simple HTTP request, or something I can use in Python with?

Thanks

Comment: No, no such thing is available. You would have to go thru “all” comments on all posts ... (quotes, because in reality that will hardly be possible.)

Comment: @CBroe so can I just find all the comments of a user  in page?

Comment: No, there is no endpoint or search for that. You would have to go through every single comment, and check who it was made by.

Comment: @CBroe so how can I get all the posts and their comments in a page?

Comment: As I already said, you can rather forget about that - it will have terrible performance, you will have to deal with pagination on multiple levels, etc. If you really think it is worth a try (believe me, it won’t be), then start with https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.0/page/feed